# Cannot convert from const_Ty2* to ValueType*

Tags: c++, constants, typename

```
template <typename ValueType> ValueType* RadixTree<ValueType>::search(std::string key) const {
    typename std::map<std::string, ValueType>::const_iterator it = radixTree.find(key);
    if (it == radixTree.end())
        return nullptr;
    return &(it->second);
}
```

Hello! above is my code which is a placeholder for my radixTree implementation. I don't understand why I need the typename before the std::map on the second line, and why &(it->second) would end up returning a const_Ty2*. I thought that in this case, const_Ty2 and ValueType were equivalent. The variable `radixTree` is currently a Map, and although I want to replace this with my radixTree implementation, I also want to understand the problem I'm getting right now. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Follow up:
I'm also getting an issue w/ this method

```
template <typename ValueType> void RadixTree<ValueType>::insert(std::string key, const ValueType& value) {
    radixTree.insert(key, value);
}
```

and radixTree is declared as
`std::map<std::string,ValueType> radixTree;`
This method gives me a really long error that I can't quite understand.

```
std::_Tree_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::pair<const std::string,ValueType>>>> std::_Tree<std::_Tmap_traits<_Kty,_Ty,_Pr,_Alloc,false>>::insert(std::_Tree_const_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::pair<const std::string,ValueType>>>>,std::pair<const std::string,ValueType> &&)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::string' to 'std::_Tree_const_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::pair<const std::string,ValueType>>>>
```

Can someone help me w/ this too? Thank you again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is const and you're correctly using a const_iterator.  This means that `it->second` is *also* const.  When you do `&it->second` that becomes a const pointer which cannot be implicitly converted to a non-const pointer (such a conversion discards the const qualifier).

It's unclear why you want a non-const pointer to an internal value.  I have to presume it's an error.  You should change the return type to `const ValueType*`.

Regarding the edit you just made to your question:

```
radixTree.insert(key, value);
```

The message is telling you that the function arguments are wrong.  Check the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) for the insert function.  You'll find that it requires a `value_type` which is a `std::pair<const Key, T>`.  The useful part of the error is here:

> cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::string' to 'std::_Tree_const_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::pair<const std::string,ValueType>>>>

There it is trying to match a call that has two arguments, which the overload resolution is trying to resolve it to `insert(const_iterator hint, const value_type &value)`.  That should tell you something is wrong.

Try this:

```
radixTree.insert(std::make_pair(key, value));
```

Comment: I understand that there is no reason why the return shouldn't be of ValueType*, but unfortunately that's what is asked of me by my professor. It's needed for the rest of my project. Do I just assume that its not possible to return a ValueType* here?

Comment: If you need to return a non-const pointer from a const search function, then you will need to store your data as pointers.  Alternatively you can use `const_cast` but that's a horrible "solution".  Go back to your professor and ask for clarification.  Research const-correctness so you can have a discussion with them about it and they know you're making an effort to understand.

Comment: Got it. I'll just store pointers for now. Maybe the professors put this limitation in place to prevent students from using STL containers to complete this part of the project? Regardless, thank you for your help!

Comment: No, I mean you can store the value in your map as a pointer instead of value.  But then you will have extra allocations and memory management problems.  I suspect there's a misunderstanding somewhere about what you're expected to achieve with what interfaces.

Comment: I do have to wonder though... If you are implementing a radix tree, then why on earth are you using `std::map` under the hood?  That is almost certainly _not_ a radix tree.

Comment: Yeah, there seems to be more errors than what there isn't. We're supposed to make our own implementations of the a radix/patricia tree, probably with a Node struct. Maybe I'll just move forward and implement the class myself first. I was using map to test if my other functionality was working first, then I wanted to implement my tree. I suppose I could complete my radix tree and test that before finishing the rest of my project as well.

Comment: If you're just trying to experiment with provided code framework, you can maybe add some `const_cast` hacks for your map.  But I would recommend instead making the tree bare-bones, turning all interfaces into stubs, and building out / testing one part of your data structure at a time.  An alternative is to create another template interface that wraps your tests, and operates on either a `std::map` or your `RadixTree`.  Then you don't need to worry about cramming a map into your own class, and you have a unified test that can work with both containers.